# Why the absence of curly brackets after FOR loop in finding factorials in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, curly-braces

This is one of the code to find the factorial of a given non negative integer. When I use the curly brackets after FOR loop for this code, the program runs very slowly. I know that for loops can be used without curly brackets for single line of code , but my code consists of two lines within the for loop. Can someone explain the reason for this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{

  int input,i,fact=1;
  
  //read user input//
  printf("Enter the number :");
  scanf("%d",&input);
  
  for(i=1;i<=input;i++)
  
   fact=fact*i;
   printf("value of factorial %d is %d",input,fact);
  
  
 }
```

Comment: where exactly did you put your curly brackets in your code ?

Comment: Because only the `faxt=fact*i;` statement should be in the loop, and not the `printf` call (which is there to print the finished result)? Output using `printf` is going to slow down the code quite considerably.

Comment: @Arsenic I  put it like this : for(i=1;i<=n;i++){ and closed the bracket after the printf statement.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, you are right. I got it now. Thank you very much. The program slowed down because of that.

Comment: regarding: `void main()`  Per the C standard, there are only two valid signatures for `main()` (although some non conforming compilers, like visual studio, will not complain when other signatures are used)  The valid signatures are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: OT: note: a relatively small value for `input` will cause the variable `fact` to overflow resulting in undefined behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [rextester](https://rextester.com/l/c_online_compiler_gcc) c compiler to analyze the run time of your program and I could see,

without curly brackets running time : **0.18 sec** and
with curly brackets running time : **0.16 sec**, which might vary time to time for approx +/- 0.05 sec. And if you are using or not using a curly brackets for the single line code in a loop which I guess should not affect the run time of the program.

You can use some other compiler and try running your code.

Answer (score 0):

you are absolutely right when saying

> for loops can be used without curly brackets for single line of code

more precisely `for loop` will run only **one** line of code if not provided with  any curly braces

so your code

```cpp
for(i=1;i<=input;i++)
   fact=fact*i;

printf("value of factorial %d is %d",input,fact);
```

will be same as

```cpp
for(i=1;i<=input;i++)
  {
   fact=fact*i;
  }

   printf("value of factorial %d is %d",input,fact);
```

but here you are putting braces ( `{}` ) around both `fact=fact*i;` and `printf("value of factorial %d is %d",input,fact);`

so just like [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) said in comments section, in this case both of these statements will be executed on each iterations of the loop and thus will be **comparatively** slower than the first one. But still that should not make big of a difference in terms of total execution time.